# Find Documents Where a Field Compares with Another in an Array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have a collection of documents that look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afa6df3a24cdb1652632ef5"),
    "createdBy" : {
        "_id" : "59232a1a41aa651ddff0939f"
    },
    "owner" : {
        "_id" : "5abc4dc0f47f732c96d84aac"
    },
    "acl" : [
        {
            "profile" : {
                "_id" : "59232a1a41aa651ddff0939f"
            }
        },
        {
            "profile" : {
                "_id" : "5abc4dc0f47f732c96d84aac"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find all documents where `createdBy._id != owner._id`, AND where the `createdBy._id` appears in one of the entries in the `acl` array. Eventually, I will want to update all such documents to set the `owner._id` field to equal the `createdBy._id` field. For now, I'm just trying to figure out how to query the subset of documents I want to update.

So far, I have come up with this:

```
db.boards.find({
  $where: "this.createdBy._id != this.owner._id", 
  $where: function() {
    return this.acl.some(
      function(e) => {
        e.profile._id === this.createdBy._id
      }, this);
  }
)
```

(I have used ES5 syntax just in case ES6 isn't ok)

But when I run this query, I get the following error:

> Error: error: {   "ok" : 0,   "errmsg" : "TypeError: e.profile is
>   undefined :\n_funcs2/<@:2:36\n_funcs2@:2:12\n",   "code" : 139 }

How do I perform this query / what is going on here? I would have expected my query to work, based on the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where) I've read. Above, `e` should be an element of the `acl` array, so I expect it to have a field `profile`, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Note, I'm using Mongo 3.2, so I can't use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/), which I've seen some resources suggest is a possibility.

**Resolution**

It turns out that I had made an incorrect assumption about the schema of this collection. The reason I was running into the above error is because some documents have an `acl` array with an element that doesn't have a `profile` field. The below query checks for this case. It also has a single `$where`, because the way I had written it originally (with two) seemed to end up giving me an OR of the conditions instead of an AND.

```
db.boards.find({
  $where: function() {
    return this.acl.some(
      function(e) => {
        e.profile !== undefined && e.profile._id === this.createdBy._id && this.createdBy._id != this.owner._id
      }, this);
  }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use `aggregate()` here with MongoDB 3.2, but just using [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) instead:

```
db.boards.aggregate([
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$and": [
          { "$ne": [ "$createdBy._id", "$owner._id" ] },
          { "$setIsSubset": [["$createdBy._id"], "$acl.profile._id"] }
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

Or with [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) for the MongoDB 3.2 shell, you just need to keep a scoped copy of `this`, and your syntax was a bit off:

```
db.boards.find({
  "$where": function() {
    var self = this;
    return (this.createdBy._id != this.owner._id)
      && this.acl.some(function(e) {
        return e.profile._id === self.createdBy._id
     })
  }
})
```

Or in an ES6 compatible environment then:

```
db.boards.find({
  "$where": function() {
    return (this.createdBy._id != this.owner._id)
      && this.acl.some(e => e.profile._id === this.createdBy._id)
  }
})
```

The aggregate is the most performant option of the two and should always be preferable to using JavaScript evalulation

And for what it's worth, the newer syntax with [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) would be:

```
db.boards.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$and": [
      { "$ne": [ "$createdBy._id", "$owner._id" ] },
      { "$in": [ "$createdBy._id", "$acl.profile._id"] }
    ]
  }
})
```

Using [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) in preference to [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) where the syntax is a little shorter.

---

> **NOTE** The only reason the JavaScript comparison here works is because you have mistakenly stored `ObjectId` values as "strings" in those fields. Where there is a "real" `ObjectId` just like in the `_id` field, the comparison needs to take the "string" from `valueOf()` in order to compare:

```
    return (this.createdBy._id.valueOf() != this.owner._id.valueOf())
      && this.acl.some(e => e.profile._id.valueOf() === this.createdBy._id.valueOf())
```

> Without that it's actually an "Object Comparison" with JavaScript and `{ a: 1 } === { a: 1 }` is actually `false`. So avoiding that complexity is another reason there are native operators for this instead.

Comment: @Ashish They often do as I just type them in here mostly and this was done over breakfast. Corrected naming and missing braces.

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for the response, though I need a little more help.

Regarding the first query (using `aggregate()`), I see it returning results where the `owner._id` = `createdBy._id`, which I don't want. I'm also going to want to update all resulting documents to set the `owner._id` to equal the `createdBy._id` (I'll edit my question to include this). I'm not sure if I can do `updateMany()` using an aggregation.

Regarding the next two (javascript) queries, I still get the same error message about "e.profile is undefined"

Comment: @Kevin None of the examples here return where those two fields match because they all have an explicit condition that says they should not. If you are seeing a different result then you probably have a "string" in one field and an `ObjectId` in another. Solving that is a different question. You can update using either `$expr` where available or `$where`, and I have run the queries by copying the data you presented in the question and my code and it all works fine. If you are doing something different then don't and I suggest you also copy the document from here and run the queries from here.

Comment: @Kevin Since there is in fact "no error" with the queries here and it works as designed with the actual data supplied in the question, then you have a means of confirming that and moving on, If you have a new question then [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). But the question asked here has been adequately answered. You were in fact given a detailed "NOTE" on `ObjectId` as your mistake seems quite clear.

Comment: So it turns out, the reason that the TypeError was happening is because some documents have `acl` array elements that do not have a `profile` field. This was my oversight, as I had made an incorrect assumption about the schema of this collection. I'll add a note about this. Thanks.